# Avoiding borrowing mutable and immutable at the same time

Tags: rust, borrowing

To add the elements of two Vecs I wrote a function like

```
fn add_components(dest: &mut Vec<i32>, first: &Vec<i32>, second: &Vec<i32>){
  for i in 0..first.len() {
    dest[i] = first[i] + second[i];
  }
}
```

And this works fine when `dest` is another Vec.

```
let mut new_components = Vec::with_capacity(components.len());
Vector::add_components(&mut new_comps, &components, &other_components);
```

But it blows up when I am trying to add in-place:

```
Vector::add_components(&mut components, &components, &other_components);
```

because now I borrow `components` as mutable and immutable at the same time. But this obviously is what I am trying to achieve.

Are there any conventional and general (meaning not only concerning Vecs) solutions to this problem which don't involve unsafe code and pointer magic?

**Another example of this problem:**

Suppose I want to overload AddAssign for a numeric type like

```
impl AddAssign<Output=&NumericType> for NumericType {
  fn add_assign(&mut self, other: &NumericType) {
    unimplemented!() // concrete implementation is not important
  }
}
```

Notice that I want to take a reference as second argument to avoid copying. This works fine when adding two different objects, but adding an object to itself creates the exact same scenario:

```
let mut num = NumericType{};
num += &num
```

I am borrowing `num` mutably and immutably at the same time. So obviously this should work and is safe, but it also is against Rust's borrowing rules.

What are the best practices (apart from copying of course) to deal with this issue, which arises in many forms?

Comment: Are the double-commas in your function parameter list just a typo, or are you actually compiling your code with the double-commas there?

Comment: @Bobulous, they were typos!

Comment: If 'extend' is not what you're looking for, then I cannot work out what you're aiming for, even with the additional example you've added. The only way to avoid copying is to either take ownership of the source, or to use references (and using references involves copying anyway). Maybe someone else can advise, but this has me scratching my head.

Comment: @Bobulous In my first example I am clearly trying to replace the elements of a Vec, which `extend`simply doesn't. 
But that also is beside the point of my question: What can I do, when a function takes the same object as mutable and immutable argument? And when the answer is that there is no canonical workaround or that it involves pointers then that would be alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic solution to this. Rust can't generically abstract over mutability in borrow checking.

You will need to have two versions of the function for in-place and destination versions.

Rust has strict aliasing rules, so `dest[i] = first[i] + second[i]` actually compiles to different code depending on whether the compiler has a guarantee that `dest` and `first` are different. Don't try to fudge it with `unsafe`, because it will be Undefined Behavior and will get miscompiled.

Comment: Miscompiled? What exactly does that mean in this context? How could my example result in machine code that produces a wrong result or even crash?

Comment: UB means the compiler can do whatever it wants, including nasal demons, and UB is non-negotiable. There are no exceptions for "but it doesn't actually matter in my case!"

In practice strict aliasing allows compiler to assume which memory won't change and reorder reads and writes however it sees fit. In non-trivial cases this can make results different. 

If you're unlucky, the optimizer may see you're "cheating" on strict aliasing, deduce it's UB by definition, and code that has UB can't exist, so it will delete the code.